# Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. useState is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

I have a GatsbyJS project and I am trying to use a Hook, however I am getting this error.

First thing I did was delete the node_modules folder and the package.json.lock file and did npm install again, did not work.

Looking at the React documentation:-

**You might have mismatching versions of React and React DOM.**
As far as I know I do not have mismatching versions.

**You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks.** - As far as I am aware I am using a component

**You might have more than one copy of React in the same app.**
I tried as the React documentation suggests:-

```js
// Add this in node_modules/react-dom/index.js
window.React1 = require('react');

// Add this in your component file
require('react-dom');
window.React2 = require('react');
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);
```

This returns false for me so I might have two React however I cannot understand how.

This is my package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-hello-world",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A simplified bare-bones starter for Gatsby",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^2.21.0",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.4.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-prefetch-google-fonts": "^1.4.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.3.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^2.4.2",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.3.0",
    "gatsby-source-strapi": "0.0.12",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.5.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "react-markdown": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.0.5"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  }
}
```

My component looks like this (just want to verify that the useState works):-

```html
import React, {useState} from "react"
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"

const query = graphql`
{
    allStrapiExperiences(sort: {fields: sequence, order: DESC}) {
      nodes {
        company
        job_title
        short_desc
        website
        address
        desc {
          id
          name
        }
        job_date
        sequence
        snapshot {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
const Experiences = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(query);
  const { allStrapiExperiences: {nodes : experiences} } = data;
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0)
  // const { company, jobt_title, short_desc, website, address, desc, job_date, sequence, snapshot } = experiences[value]

  return (
    <div>Some details go here</div>
  )
}


export default Experiences
```

And I am calling this component in the experience.js page:-

```html
import React from "react"
import Experiences from "../components/Experiences/Experiences"
import Layout from "../components/Generic/Layout"

export default () => {

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Experiences />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

I have looked at some posts online, and did some troubleshooting but so far I cannot understand why I am having this problem.

Any ideas why I might be getting this error?

Thanks for your help and time

---

UPDATE

Just a small update on this, I could not solve the issue, so i took the unwanted route but I thing the best one at the moment to start with the basic blog starter project and start building up from that.  Infact, the hooks do work in this project, so I guess I have some mess with dependencies but I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Comment: If you take `useState()` out of that component do you still get the same error? Also can you paste more of the error in there?

Answer (score 0):

1. This might seem weird, but can you move your query definition into the call to `useStaticQuery`? Gatsby uses static analysis to extract these and historically there have been some issues defining a query and assigning it to a variable in this way. For example:

   ```js
   const Experiences = () => {
     const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
       {
         allStrapiExperiences(sort: {fields: sequence, order: DESC}) {
           ...
         }
       }
     `);
   }
   ```
2. To ensure you don't have multiple versions of React being used, you can try this:

   ```js
   exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, actions }) => {
     actions.setWebpackConfig({
       resolve: {
         // Ensure all dependencies use the same instance of React
         alias: { react: path.resolve("./node_modules/react") },
       },
     })
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi Corey I did the first change but still the same error.  Where do I implement the 2nd change?  Is that in the gatsby-config.js file?

Comment: Did some research and added the 2) in gatsby-node.js file still no luck :(

Comment: I think you'll need to isolate this further then. E.g. try without the static query, try without rendering the layout, etc until it's clear where the error is coming from.

Comment: Also, in the future don't delete your package-lock.json file when debugging—it holds the specific versions of your dependencies. Without it you wind up re-resolving versions, drastically increasing the scope of changes you need to contend with.

Comment: Hi corey, thanks a lot for your help.  I tried everything I could, even yarn install --flat and I was choosing 1 version of every dependency, but it got to a point where it was easier to just start fresh, and add my components one by one and testing along the way.  So far so good!